# Run Vue tests in Docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, pm2

I have a Dockerfile

```
FROM node:19-bullseye-slim

WORKDIR /app
# Install prerequisites
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
gnupg \
curl \
bash 

COPY . /app

CMD ./bootstrap.sh
```

and a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

npm add yarn 
yarn add pm2 ---dev
yarn install
npx playwright install-deps chromium
yarn test
echo "Finished"
```

The commands

1. install yarn ,
2. install dependencies from my app,
3. install playwright chromium browser
4. Run a test command which is in my package.json file as "test"

   ```
    "test": "pm2 start server.js && npm run test:cucumber",
   ```

   "test:cucumber": "cucumber-js --require ./cucumber.js --require ./tests/e2e-playwright/step-definitions/**/*.js -f json:cucumber_report.json --publish-quiet",

That command should start the dev server for vue and then run the cucumber tests

My server.js file is

```
module.exports  = {
    apps: [
      {
        name: "WEB",
        script: "./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js",
        args: "serve"
      }
    ]
```

};

pm2 starts server.js , which calls vue-cli-service serve (starts the vue dev-server)

But the vue dev server doesn't start and my tests fail as the application isn't available

If I run vue-cli-service serve everything works as expected , and the website is available at http:localhost:8080

Can someone tell me how to get pm2 to run the server and it will be available ?
Can someone tell me if I can run my tests and connect with port 8080 in the Docker container , or would I have to point my tests to use host.docker.internal ? And how would I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to run the tests from host against the Docker container? What command are you using to start the container?

Comment: No , I'm trying to run my tests within the Docker container if that is possible. So I have containerized my application and started it using vue-cli-service serve , now I want to run my cucumber tests against the running application . All of it is within the container. I hope that makes some kind of sense.

Comment: Please, try analyzing your container logs. Does the container log any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are running the server and test *concurrently*, like with '&' or https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

The `"test": "pm2 start server.js && npm run test:cucumber"` seems like it first launches the server, then waits for server to exit, and only then tries to statr tests.

Basically, try running the same commangs (or the same bash) on your own PC before putting it into container

Also,

- your `yarn add pm2 ---dev` speaks `--dev` incorrectly
- cucumber is likely to be a test dependency, so you may be not installing it
- You can install the dev dependencies in `NODE_ENV=production` with `yarn install --production=false`, you may need that
- 
- node@>=16 container iirc provides yarn by default

Comment: Thanks for your  answer , and apologise for not being clearer in my question. I have found a solution using commands to start the pm2 instance "pm2 serve dist 8080 --spa", which runs the Vue app from the dist directory after building and keeps the server running, then  "cucumber-js --require ./cucumber.js --require ./tests/e2e-playwright/step-definitions/**/*.js -f json:cucumber_report.json --publish-quiet", to run the cucumber tests , then close the pm2 instance using "pm2 delete all". This works on my local machine and in GCP Cloudbuild, I haven't tested in Docker locally yet.